# If $f : X \to Y$ is a finite morphism of projective varieties. Then is the length of a fiber constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a finite morphism of projective varieties. Then is the length of a fiber constant? (If true, it should be the degree of the extension of function fields.)

This would follow if I knew that $f$ was flat, from the Euler characteristic being constant on fibers. I'm not sure if it is - for smooth curves it is, but that's because flatness over a smooth curve is easy to check. I can assume that $Y$ is smooth. ($Y$ is actually a Grassmanian in the application, and actually I also know that $f$ is generically one to one, and I am trying to conclude that it is one-to-one.)

In commutative algebra terms, I'm also vaguely asking:

If $A$ is a finite extension of $B$, and $B$ is normal, then for each maximal ideal $m$ of $B$, is the length of $A / mA$ constant? Or, if $K$ if a finite extension of degree d of $Frac(B)$, and $A$ is the integral closure of $B$ in $K$, are the fibers of $B$ over $A$ all of length $d$? This doesn't sound right...

I can assume that $Y$ is smooth (hence Cohen-Macauley) and that $X$ is a finite cover of $Y$. Does it follow that $X$ is CM? Then one could apply the "Miracle flatness theorem."

Comment: Any non surjective closed immersion of  projective varieties (smooth or not) is finite, but has fibers both of zero and of non zero length.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Oh yeah, that's a good point. In my case I know that it is surjective though. (The map arises as a projection from an incidence correspondence over a Grassmannian.)

Comment: The normalization of **any** singular projective curve is finite, surjective and has fibers both of length 1 and of length greater than 1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Also true. Thanks. Let me think then. I guess I should just ask the question I want answered, and not beat around the bush. :)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032062/a-surjective-branched-covering-of-a-normal-variety-which-is-generically-injecti

Comment: Another example is the map $\mathbb{A}^2 \to X \subset \mathbb{A}^3$, $(x,y) \mapsto (x^2,xy,y^2)$, where $X$ is the quadratic cone. A general fiber has length 2, but not the fiber over $0$.

Comment: In fact, the length of fibers of a finite map is constant, if and only if the map is FLAT.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for the example and comment. So, maybe the best one can say is that there is a generic length of fibers in general, coming from the degree of the function field extension.

Comment: Yes. And this generic length also equals the rank of the sheaf $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$